# Meaning of y’s and i’s

Tags: meaning

> Toby remembered Rachel telling him that parents who sub out y’s for i’s in the middle of their girls’ names, and vice versa at the end, are not giving their daughters much of a chance in the world.

Could anyone help me understand what *y’s* and *i’s* mean in this sentence?

Comment: The implication is that naming your daughter ***Lili*** or ***Judi*** rather than ***Lily, Judy*** is an affectation that will tarnish her reputation throughout her life (if she came from "weird" parents, she's probably always going to be a bit weird herself).

Comment: Haha, good to know, thanks.

Comment: The strange thing about it is although I knew straight away what the writer was getting at, I actually found it quite difficult to come up with a couple of examples (and I'm not particularly impressed with the two I eventually *did* settle on there! :) All I kept thinking of was ***Toni*** instead of ***Tony***, but that's not a good example either because imho the orthography switch there is primarily to distinguish the male and female forms (as is the case for several other names that are gender-neutral in *sound*).

Comment: Maybe I'm old fashioned, but shortening Nicola, Nicolette, etc, to Nikki really burns me up! What's wrong with Nicky? In the 60s the i for y thing was something we Brits thought of as mainly American, but it seems to have taken root here now.

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to the way that the names are spelt. For instance Linda and Lynda, Fiona and Fyona, Tony and Toni. Andy and Andi. "Sub out" either compares the changing of the spelling from the more common to less common version with the process of "sub editing" in publishing, particularly newspapers or refers to "substituting" one for the other.

I find it a little difficult to work out the direction of the change referred to by "sub out" because it could mean replacing 'y's with 'i's or the other way around. Also some names are normally spelt with a 'y' and some with an 'i' both in the middle of and at the end of a name so it's hard to see what general rule "Rachel" is proposing.

Comment: Further confusion comes from gendered spellings  in a couple of those examples - Tony is usually male, Toni female, and similarly for Andy/Andi (though either is rare as a female name)

Comment: I agree that it's aksing a lot of the reader to work it out, but "sub out y's for i's" unambiguously means take the y *out* and put the i in its place. Consider that writing, "sub in y's for i's" means the opposite. (I suppose I find "sub in" more inherently clear.)

Comment: @ChrisH I tend to agree that Andi and Toni look like female names but in the UK there is a male TV presenter called Andi Peters and a hairdressing chain called Toni and Guy which is named after the Mascolo brothers who founded it.

Comment: @maxnorton I wonder if "sub out" is more familiar to an American readership. I understood it in principle but it wasn't immediately familiar. I agree that "sub in 'i's for 'y's" is less ambiguous. I'd prefer "sub out 'y's with 'i's"

Comment: You’re right, “with” seems preferable to “for” in the “out” case. “For” is much better than “with” in the “in” case.

Comment: @BoldBen I remembered Andi Peters (hence my "usually") but while I've heard of Toni & Guy  I know nothing about the founders

Comment: @ChrisH Neither did I until I looked them up! Thank the Lord for [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toni_%26_Guy) :-)